# Limitar ejes para que vayan de un rango a otro sin problema

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

Estoy intentando generar un gráfico ternario con tipos de suelos conformados por diferentes combinaciones de `Arcilla`, `Arena` y `MO`. A su vez calculo el crecimiento de las plantas en los tipos de suelos conformados. Los valores van de 0 a 100% en `Arcilla` y `Arena`, mientras que para `MO` es de 0 a 10%. El problema es que utilizando `coord_tern` y/o `tern_limits` no logro acortar el `eje R (MO)` para que los puntos se distribuyan por todo el gráfico y no solamente se concentren en un extremo puesto que las escalas `default` para los ejes van de 0 a 100.

Si no fui claro en la consulta háganmelo saber por favor.

```
ggtern(data = Libro1,mapping = aes(x= Arcilla, y= Arena, z= MO)) +
coord_tern(Tlim = ("0,100"), Llim = ("0,100"), Rlim = ("0,10")) +
tern_limit(T = 1, L = 1, R= 0.1) + stat_density_tern(geom='polygon', 
  aes(fill=..level..), bins=5, color='grey') + geom_point()
```

[image: Gráfico obtenido]

Comment: Hola Ignacio. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de mostrar lo intentado y por qué no te funcionó. Lee [ask] para hacer preguntas de más calidad. Un saludo

Comment: podrías incluir algo de código? ayuda muchísimo para tener una idea cómo resolverlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es posible realizar lo que necesitas por limitaciones propias del paquete `ggtern`. Cada eje en el gráfico debe sumar lo mismo que el resto. Como T 0:100, L 20:120 y R 100:200. En el caso de lo que deseas realizar alza el siguiente error (por la misma razón que expongo):

```
library(ggtern)

Libro1 <- data.frame(Arcilla=1:100,Arena=1:100, MO = seq(from=0,to=10, length.out = 100))

ggtern(data = Libro1,mapping = aes(x= Arcilla, y= Arena, z= MO)) +
  scale_T_continuous(limits = c(0,100))+
  scale_L_continuous(limits = c(0,100))+
  scale_R_continuous(limits = c(0,10))

##     T   L  R Sum
## 1 100   0  0 100
## 2   0 100  0 100
## 3   0   0 10  10
## Error: Invalid Ternary Limits, Each Point Must Sum to Unity...
```

Te recomiendo expresar las unidades de manera diferente (como MO x 10^-1) para poder utilizar la misma escala que `Arena`y `Arcilla`:

```
library(ggtern)

Libro1 <- data.frame(Arcilla=1:100,Arena=1:100, MO = seq(from=0,to=10, length.out = 100))

Libro1$MO <- Libro1$MO*10

ggtern(data = Libro1,mapping = aes(x= Arcilla, y= Arena, z= MO)) +
  Tlab('Arena')+Llab('Arcilla')+Rlab(expression(paste('MOx10'^-1)))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Aldo! Si, la solución más sencilla fue la de expresar el valor de MOx1/10. Saludos